# Is it appropriate to ask if remote work or alternate hours are possible for an intern position?

Tags: internship

The position in discussion did not specifically mentioned that remote work or flexible hours are offered on the posting. As this is a classic engineering office job. However most of the work is on the computer, and the office does have laptops which are given to those going on trips. It is the classic everyone comes in at either 8 or 9 and leaves by 6 kind of atmosphere.

I will not be the only intern, but I would be the one with the most experience.
I was wondering if it is appropriate to ask if I can work flexible hours or do part of the work remote? I would be a full time intern, and I plan to take course(s) related to my degree in parallel to the internship.

Partly due to student loans, partly because I would have a significant amount of free time in comparison to being a full time student, and it would be more productive and better for my study habits if there isn't a large gap in studying.
As well, the course(s) in question fill up to capacity during fall and winter, but are also offered during the summer which have lower enrollment.

Additional notes: this is a paid internship. It is not software engineering. My commute time would be 3-4 hours / day

Comment: Does your office have remote access? or is it cloud based? These two options would allow you to access files without requiring a company laptop.

Comment: Perhaps they only took you on as an intern so that your experience would help the other interns - you being at home defeats that...

Comment: 3 - 4 hours ???????????????

Comment: There are a lot of things unclear for us to provide further suggestions. For example: What is the intern position about? What industry is it? Is the company having majority of its employee work remotely? And probably most importan0lyt: **What do you want to get from this internship?** Are you looking for chance of full-time employment in this company? Do you just want another experience line or some reference in your resume? Do you just want few weeks of paystub so you don't have to work in subway? Or only thing you care is the experience you get from the process?

Comment: @Fattie my first job out of college came with a 3-hour daily commute. Here in Atlanta, Georgia at least, it's not at all uncommon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it appropriate to ask if remote work or alternate hours are possible for an intern position?

You can always ask. There is nothing "inappropriate" about asking for work schedule. However, keep in mind

1. Most workplaces do want interns to work from office so that they can closely monitor the work.
2. In your case if most employees work from 8 to 6 from office and get laptop only when traveling, then it may be even more hard for you to get that approval.
3. Like other answer suggested, there is lot to learn by coming to office and interacting with people. If you are hoping to convert this to full time opportunity, then even more important for you to increase your company network.

So bottom line is you can surely ask once gently but do not push for it.

Answer (score 5):

As an intern you are there to learn from those in the field and gain experience.

How much do you think you can learn from others and gain experience working from home?

Comment: A significant portion of the work would be through self learn. I would be a senior intern, soon to graduate, so I imagine a higher degree of independence would be expected from me. 
Going  in 2-3 times a week just to clarify things and attend meetings would not be an issue. 
Just because I'm not sitting beside them, doesn't mean I wouldn't have access to resources to learn more.

Comment: @Mel I just think its a bad idea. You're an intern. I never even heard of a "senior intern". As an intern when they say "jump" you say "how high".  Demanding perks like working from home before you've even graduated is not a good way to form a relationship with a company that has so much say over your future. Just my humble opinion. No offense or disrespect intended at all :)

Comment: its senior in a way that I have had done this type of work prior for 8 month before vs those who are just starting with this type of work. 

why is remote work considered a perk? aren't the expectations of deliverable deadlines and quality held to the same standard?

Comment: also to clarify in Canada interns ( co - op)  are ranked junior, senior 
I can see why it would be an alien expression for those not familiar

Comment: @Mel you can ask them, obviously, nothing is stopping you. I have no idea what they might respond with as I have never heard of an intern making demands like these.  Please be sure to update us with what they say as I am now genuinely curious to see how this turns out for you.

Comment: Why is remote work considered a perk from your perspective? A google search turns up quiet a number of remote internships, not exclusive to software.

Comment: My previous (US based) employer had Highschool/freshman/.../senior intern positions so it's not just a Canadian term; they were split between long term co-opish slots and single summer ones.  At least on the software and engineering side the lower half was mostly notional; we rarely hired people without 2 years of schooling.  AFAIK it was mostly administrative for setting pay levels, meaningful 'seniority' had more to do with how long you'd been with the company and thus how clued in on your project you were.

Comment: As an intern, a lot of what they want you to learn is how to transition from being a student to functioning effectively as part of a team in an office environment. You're not going to self-learn *that* remotely.